# How to plot a barplot (base R) with more than 200 columns with different color in R?

Tags: r

I use the code `coul = brewer.pal(5, "Set2")` and plot the barplot `barplot(data[,1], col=coul)` by columns. However, I actually have more than 200 rows for each column. How can I expand the number of colour? * I use the `barplot` function in base R.

Comment: Hi, you may want to include a [small reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/11810235) with more detail to make it easier for people to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

colorRampPalette receives a color vector, later you pass the number of colors you want between those colors.

```
colorFunc <- colorRampPalette(c('#ff0000', '#ff0000', '#00aaff',...))
colors <- colorFunc(dim(df)[2])
```

Here I passed the number of columns, so it will return as many colors as columns, if you want as many colors as rows:

```
colors <- colorFunc(dim(df)[1])
```